# Add custom Item Template to Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, itemtemplate

I have created a Custom Item Template within Visual Studio using ASPX and C#.

I understand how to export and import the template. However this gets saved locally within my PC's C:\ drive.

> C:\Users[USERNAME]\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ItemTemplates

I am wondering how i would attach it to the website's solution and make it accessible for whoever opens the solution on their PC. Without having to import or export it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to add it to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem ,you have to add the item template to Assets, in source.extension.vsixmanifest.

That should already work.

[image]